# A Better Way To Print Many Functions

Tags: python

So I am finishing my CodeAcademy's Python course and on this specific lesson I have to print different functions. I wonder if there is a more efficient/simple way to print all those functions instead the one I am using.

```
print print_grades(grades), '\n', grades_sum(grades), '\n', grades_average(grades),'\n', grades_variance(grades), '\n', grades_std_deviation(variance)
```

It prints:

```
100
100
90
40
80
100
85
70
90
65
90
85
50.5
None 
1045.5 
80.4230769231 
334.071005917 
18.2776094147
```

Comment: Please correctly format your code and provide us something we can run to see how it's working.

Comment: `for function in (print_grades, ...): print function(grades)`? Functions are first class objects in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your functions inside a list, and use list comprehension to execute them.

```
funcs = [func1, func2, ..]
[f(grades) for f in funcs]
```

Comment: I belive that using a side-effect like `print`ing inside a list comprehension that is immediately thrown away is generally considered bad programming style. You should at least note such strange constructions as a comment in your code.

Comment: Well this was used just for the example. Obviously you should do something with the list, otherwise you should use generators. But agreed, I removed it from the code